# how do i list existing files in a directory and subdirectories using recursion?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am wondering if it's possible to put all files into a list even if they are present in different subdirectories without using os.walk

The function i have written does the job, but i don't want the files to be displayed in nested lists. I need them to be in a single list.

```
import os

def cerca(dir1): 
    
    lista1 = [] 
    for fname in os.listdir(dir1): 
        path = os.path.join(dir1,fname)
        if fname.startswith('.') : continue 
        if os.path.isfile(path): 
            lista1.append(fname)
    return lista1

def directory(dir1): 
    
    lista2 = cerca(dir1) 
    for fname in os.listdir(dir1): 
        path = os.path.join(dir1,fname) 
        if os.path.isdir(path): 
            ret = directory(path)
            lista2.append(ret)  
    return lista2 


output = [['looney-tunes.txt', [[['minnie.txt']]]], ['minnie.txt', ['looney-tunes.txt']],[['minnie.txt'], [['looney-tunes.txt']]]]
```

The output should instead be:

```
['looney-tunes.txt','minnie.txt','minnie.txt','looney-tunes.txt','minnie.txt','looney-tunes.txt']
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a flat list out of list of lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flatten an irregular list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158395/flatten-an-irregular-list-of-lists)

Comment: Nope it doesn't

Answer (score 2):

Currently, you're only using the `list.append` method, which is why you're getting nested lists. You don't need to flatten the list if you make use of the `list.extend` method:

```
def walk(root):
    files = []
    for e in os.listdir(root):
        path = os.path.join(root, e)
        print(path)
        if os.path.isfile(path):
            files.append(e)
        else:
            files.extend(walk(path))

    return files
```

And then call the function like so:

```
root = "path-to-directory"
files = walk(root)
```

Firstly, we need to initialize an empty list, `files` so that we can keep track of the files that have already been iterated over. Now we just have to list the files using `os.listdir` and do a simple check if it's a file or a directory.

If it's a file, `list.append` does the trick.

If it's a directory, we need to use `list.extend` because if you append a list to a list, you're just going to get nested lists, like so:

```
files = ["top_file.txt", ["nested_file_0.txt", "nested_file_1.txt"]]
```

Using extend, we get something like this instead:

```
files = ["top_file.txt", "nested_file_0.txt", "nested_file_1.txt"]
```

Comment: @alex108 no problem, enjoy!

Comment: Hey, one important question. What would you add to the code if you wanted to search the files that are present at a given depth?.

For example, if 3 depth is given, i should output only the files at depth 3.

Comment: You should pass a `max_depth` and a `current_depth` parameter to the function so that the signature is now `walk(root, max_depth, current_depth=0)`. This is so that you can keep track of the depths as recursion continues. You should increment the depth like so: `files.extend(walk(path, 3, current_depth+1))`. You should then have an `if statement` to check whether or not `max_depth == current_depth`.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know why you do not want to use `os.walk`, as it is the most efficient way of recursively listing a directory's contents. If you really cannot use `os.walk` (for whatever reason), take no notice of this answer. But in case you might consider using `os.walk`, I made an exmaple of how,

```py
import os

def walk(path):
    filelist = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        filelist.append(list(filter(None, root.split(os.path.sep)))[-1]) # get the directory name we are currently in without the path and append it to the list
        filelist.extend(dirs + files) # extend the list  with the directories and files
    return filelist
```

To have a flat list without having to flatten it, you must use [`list.extend`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) instead of [`list.append`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists).

Comment: *I am wondering if it's possible to put all files into a list even if they are present in different subdirectories __without using os.walk__*

Comment: @Tomerikoo why should `os.walk` not be used ?

Comment: How can I know? That's part of the OP's requirements... (If it wasn't clear, the above comment is a quote from the question...)

Comment: @Tomerikoo TL;DR : I oversaw the first paragraph of the OP's question, thanks !

Comment: @alex108 ok, then just use extend instead of append as shown in my example !